# NP-Complete and some decision problems on graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, np-complete, np

We know about NP-Complete and NP-Hard, and NP Class. I want to conclude some tips on following problem, that take from 2008 Mid exam on MIT.

Decision Version of which of the following problem for a connected undirected weighted graph G is NP-Complete?

> a) finding maximal matching.
>
> b) finding maximum Hamiltonian cycle
>
> c) finding maximum Eulelrian cycle
>
> d) finding maximum cut

How can categorized these problem in a simple manner for me? i.e. NP or NP-Complete or NP-Hard.

Comment: Finding a maximum Hamilton cycle is NP-hard. None of the problems are in NP, because they're not decision problems.

Comment: I Think the op talk about NP-Complete? @DavidEisenstat.

Comment: NP-completeness implies membership in NP, so none of them are NP-complete either.

Comment: sorry, there is a typo.

Comment: i edit the questions. sorry @DavidEisenstat

Answer (score 1):

There are poly-time algorithms for computing maximal matchings (e.g., greedy; Edmonds's Blossom algorithm computes a *maximum* matching in poly-time) and Eulerian cycles. The decision versions trivially belong to NP (P, in fact).

Hamilton cycle and max cut are well-known NP-hard problems. The decision versions are in NP so thus are NP-complete.

Comment: @AliMovagher Misunderstood max cut as min cut. Fixed.

Comment: please clear you answer, I confused :) you are so expert. others want to learn from you Dr. please make clear which of them is NP or NP-Complete or NP-Hard to learn

Comment: @AliMovagher Both NP-hard problems appear in Garey and Johnson. This is not supposed to be an exercise in algorithm design or hardness proofs.